# Ubuntu is not recognizing android phone

Tags: drivers, 14.04, android, adb

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Android SDK, ADB and some other stuff to develop android app on Ubuntu but phone is not recognizing by computer. Adb is working and phone debug settings are ok.

How can I fix this?

Edit: I had set up phone but not working(http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

Device is Samsung Galaxy S4 v4.2.2.

Comment: How is ADB working if the phone is not recognized? What is working and what is not exactly?

Comment: @kraxor `adb devices` command is giving `List of devices attached`. My phone is Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: Does the device show up in the file manager? Do you get a prompt the phone to allow the computer to connect to it? have you enabled debugger mode?

Comment: Debugger mode is enable but I can't see device anywhere. Computer does not detect phone.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Accessing files on the device? `adb`? `fastboot`?

Comment: I will develop android app so I have to test app using adb on my phone.